# Comparing tuples to strings

Tags: python, sqlite, python-3.4, bottle

I am trying to retrieve a user from my sessions table in the database. In my unit test i get an error:

```
line 138, in test_session_user
    self.assertEqual(nick_from_cookie, nick)
AssertionError: ('Bobalooba',) != 'Bobalooba'
```

I understand that this is because my code is returning a tuple when the test is comparing my return value against a string therefore it is not matching.

Is there a way for me to do this comparison using the tuple or is their a better way to query the result i need. Below is the table im using aswell as my function:

```
def session_user(db):
    """try to
    retrieve the user from the sessions table
    return usernick or None if no valid session is present
    """
    cursor = db.cursor()
    sessionid = bottle.request.get_cookie(COOKIE_NAME)
    usernick = None
    if sessionid:
        cursor.execute("SELECT usernick FROM sessions WHERE sessionid=?", (sessionid,))
        usernick = cursor.fetchone()
    return usernick
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
row = cursor.fetchone()
if row:
    usernick, = row
```

Note the unpacking of the tuple.

Comment: When i try this i get a error 'line 66, in session_user
    usernick, = cursor.fetchone()
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
'

Comment: Then the result of your query is empty. Check it first before unpacking the tuple.

Comment: How do i go about doing that? sorry python is definitely not my strong suit. I'm new to it.